# Sqlite3 import csv not working

Tags: csv, sqlite

I followed instructions on this page https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html#section_8 to import a csv file (on Linux) but failed:

```
$ sqlite3 testdb
-- Loading resources from /home/abcd/.sqliterc

SQLite version 3.7.17 2013-05-20 00:56:22
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> .mode csv
sqlite> .import sample_data.csv maintable
Error: no such table: maintable
sqlite>
```

It is a simple csv file:

```
$ cat sample_data.csv
roll_no,candidate_name,subject,marks,grade
1234567,ABCD EFGH,301,38,A2
7654321,XYZ ABC,301,64,B1
9876564,ABCD FGLG,301,50,A1
...
```

testdb does not exist to begin with and should be a new database to be created. However, only a 0 byte database is created and the csv file is not imported (see error above).

It does work if I manually create a table with all fields. Why are the fields not being created automatically as mentioned on the official page of https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html#section_8 . Is it a version problem?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it was a bug and is fixed by now as it works for me (Mac OS X) and your version is a bit old.

```
$ sqlite3 testdb
SQLite version 3.8.10.2 2015-05-20 18:17:19
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> .mode csv
sqlite> .import sample_data.csv  maintable
sqlite> SELECT * FROM maintable;
1234567,"ABCD EFGH",301,38,D2
7654321,"XYZ ABC",301,64,C1
9876564,"ABCD FGLG",301,50,D1
sqlite> .exit
```